How to change the vertical scroll bar width using internal css only in react.js?
I am trying to apply this code to change the scrollbar's width using internal css(i.e css
stored in the javascript object) but it's not working. I require to change the width of the scrollbar using internal CSS only in react.js project.
export default function ButtonsContainer() {
  let cssobject = {
    secondDiv_css: {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      height: "8vh",
      overflowY: "scroll",
      // scrollbarWidth:"thin",
      "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
        width: "1px", // Width of the scrollbar
      },
      "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
        backgroundColor: "#888", // Color of the thumb
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <List style={cssobject["secondDiv_css"]}>
      {["btn1", "btn2", "btn3", "btn4"].map((txt) => {
        return (
          <ListItem>
            <Button>{txt}</Button>
          </ListItem>
        );
      })}
    </List>
  );
}



Pseudo-classes are not allowed in inline styles in CSS. Alternatively, you can assign className to the element and style appropriately in your stylesheet. If you are importing List from a package/library and they don't provide the customization that allows you to declare your custom className you can wrap the component inside a div and assign a className to it
<div>
 <List className='custom-list-wrapper'>
  ...
 </List>
</div>

In your stylesheet you can do this where .list-library-class is the default className for the List component as defined by the package creators, you can get this by inspecting the component in your chrome dev tool inspect element
.custom-list-wrapper .list-library-class{
  ...
}

